# How to add Static route after virtnetwork service started

Tags: centos7, virtualization, kvm

I need to add this route after server booted and virtnetwork service started staticly

```
ip route add x.x.x.x/27 via 192.168.1.1 dev viifbr0
```

Answer (score -1):

for static route:
route add 192.168.100.0 gateway 192.168.100.10 ens33

Default route:
route add 0.0.0.0 gateway 192.168.100.10 ens33